# Martingales in gambler's ruin problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

For a Brownian motion $B$, set $T_a=\inf\{t\ge 0: B_t=a\}$. Then we can say $B_{t\land T_a}$ is bounded above by $|a|$.

My question is that for [Gambler's ruin and martingale](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2119476/gamblers-ruin-and-martingale)

set-up for the gambler's ruin problem:

> $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ are i.i.d. rv with $P(X_1=1)=1-P(X_1=-1)=p$ and $p\in (0,1),\ p\neq 1/2$. We have integers $0<a<b$, a sequence $S_0:=a$ with
> $S_n:=S_{n-1}+X_n\quad n\geq 1$ and $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ and $T$ is the stopping time when either $S_n=0$ or $S_n=b$.

> I had to show that the following two are martingales, so this is known:
> $$M_n:=\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{S_n}\qquad N_n:=S_n -n(2p-1)$$

Can we say $M_{n\land T}$ and $N_{n\land T}$ bounded above (such as $M_{n\land T}$ bounded above by $\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{b}\lor 1$ and $N_{n\land T}$ bounded above by $b-T(2p-1)\lor -T(2p-1)$)? But I am not sure about $N_{n\land T}$.

Then they are all uniformly integrable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bounds you have written are indeed true (for the second one, there is no need to write the max though), and you can give similar bounds from below:
$$0\leq M_{n\wedge T}\leq 1\vee \left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^b, $$
and,
$$
 -T(2p-1)\leq N_{n\wedge T}\leq b-T(2p-1).
$$
These are uniform (random) bounds in $n$ that are integrable, since $T$ is. Thus they are all uniform integrable.

Comment: But $T$ is finite which is not bounded. Can we say it is bounded?

Comment: T is not bounded, and $N_{\min\{n,T\}}$ is not bounded from below. But you asked for uniform integrability, not boundedness